# update code issue in oracle database its giving a error "ora-00933 sql command not properly ended update"

Tags: python-3.x, oracle

try:
        con=cx_Oracle.connect("system/abc123")
        cursor=con.cursor()

```
    rno = int( entupRno.get() )
    name = entupName.get()
    marks = int( entupMarks.get() )

    sql = "UPDATE student set name = '%s' and marks = '%d' where rno= '%d' "
    args = (name,marks,rno)
    cursor.execute(sql%args)
    con.commit()
    msg=str(cursor.rowcount) + "rows updated"
    messagebox.showinfo("Success ",msg)

except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    con.rollback()
    messagebox.showerror("Failure: ",e)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should replace `and` with `,` in your update statement.

```
sql = "UPDATE student set name = '%s' , marks = '%d' where rno= '%d' "
```